# How to send data from Javascript datepicker form to <cfform>

Tags: javascript, forms, coldfusion

I'm user a Javascript datepicker from mobiscroll to allow the user to select a date and submit it with just mouse clicks. I need to send this data to a ColdFusion query. I was already using the datepicker included with ColdFusion, but as it runs on Flash its not ideal for use over different systems. Using CF's native datepicker I was receiving data from the form as Form.SubmitDate. I can't seem to find the right syntax to enclose the input using cfform.

Script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
$('#SubmitDate').mobiscroll().date({
    theme: 'default',
    display: 'modal',
    mode: 'scroller',
    dateOrder: 'yyyy mm dd '
   });    
});

</script>
```

Input element

```
    <input name="SubmitDate" id="SubmitDate" class="i-txt" >
```

Comment: http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/examples/cf_jquery/jquery_cf_datepicker.cfm

Comment: Not that I'm a fan of it because it can still be a pain but what version of CF are you using? As of CF8 `<cfinput type = "datefield">` supports an HTML/javascript date picker using the extJS library. http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_07.html